# Problem with a northwind database installation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a instnwnd.sql which is a script file for northwind database installation. I don't know how to install this database. I have tried the procedure [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227484(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227484%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) but I could not succeed. The error comes out to be "The user is not associated with a trusted sql server connection" I read some where u can do it using query analyser, but what is the sql statement for that ?? Somebody please help me.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you followed the instructions from the MSDN page, and you ran

> osql -U sa -P [password] -i instnwnd.sql

you *did* see the note about replacing [password] with the actual administrative password you created when you installed SQL Server, right?

> **Note** For [password], type the system administrator password that you
>   created earlier.

Just open the `instnwnd.sql` file (which is plain text) in Notepad, copy all the text, and paste it into the query window in SQL Server Management Studio. Then press F5 to run the SQL script.

Comment: @ken i don't have a administrative password

Comment: @user653622, then you can't install NorthWind (or any other databases), or do most things with SQL Server. You need the SA (system administrator) password; when you installed SQL Server 2000, the installer asks for a password for the SA user. Without one, you're out of luck.

Comment: @ken when i login to my computer i don't provide any. I just directly login. But your idea of copying and pasting into query window in SQL Server management studio did work. I'm thankful to you for that.

Comment: @user653622, it's not the *Windows* password. It's the specific SQL Server 2000 SA password (the SQL Server system administrator). It has nothing to do with login to your computer. SQL Server Management Studio also would require the SA password (or at least another administrative account user and password); you've apparently got SQL Server set up to use Windows authorization or save your credentials. Glad you got it sorted out, anyway. :)

Comment: @ken In that case yes you are right, my sql server uses windows authorization. I don't have a specific username or password for log-in to sql server. I just login using windows credentials.

Comment: osql -E will work as well, just leave off -U and -P, it will use your windows authentication

Answer (score 1):

To overcome the "sa" problem I used this and it worked for me.

`C:\Users\UserName>sqlcmd -E -i c:\path\to\instnwnd.sql`

The website I got this from is
[Install Northwind Database](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/03/04/what-is-and-how-do-i-install-the-northwind-database/).